# Javascript creating arrays from strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have following code:

```
var selector="a,b,c/m,n",
property = "width,height/font-size";
```

I want to group each set of strings (separated by forward slash) to new array.

so I would (basically) end up with this:

```
var selector_array1 = [a,b,c]; 
var selector_array2 = [m,n]; 
----

var property_array1 = [width,height]; 
var property_array2 = [font-size]; 
....
```

so I would end up with 2 for loops (I think), like:

```
for(outer loop){//for each selector array
    for(inner loop){//for each item in selector array apply each property in property array

    }
}
```

Bear in mind it can only have 1 value/property like (so no forward slashes to split):

```
var selector="a/m",
property = "width/font-size";
```

or like this:

```
var selector="a",
property = "width";
```

Comment: What would be the output from `selector="a"`? An array `["a"]` and an empty array `[]`? You can still use `.split()` for this.

Comment: Result arrays must contain strings or variables? What are `a,b,c` in `var selector_array1 = [a,b,c];`?

Comment: `var selector="a,b,c/m,n", arr = selector.split("/").map(e => e.split(",")); console.log(arr);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the ones with no slashes. Just split once on slashes then split those results on commas.

```js
function extractData(input) {
  // Separate by /'s
  return input.split('/')
    .map(function(str) {
      // For each of the new strings, split them on commas
      return str.split(',');
    });
}

var data = extractData('a,b,c/width,height');
console.log(data[0].toString(), '|', data[1].toString());

data = extractData('a,b,c');
console.log(data[0].toString());

data = extractData('a/width,height');
console.log(data[0].toString(), '|', data[1].toString());

data = extractData('a/width');
console.log(data[0].toString(), '|', data[1].toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to use the split method of the String prototype:

```js
var selector="a,b,c/m,n",
property = "width,height/font-size";

function splitString(s){
  // Split the string with the character /
  // And loop through the array
  return s.split('/').map(function(stringWithComa){
    // Return the result of the string split
    return stringWithComa.split(',')
  })
}

console.log(splitString(selector));
console.log(splitString(property));
```

Hope it helps ;) Dont hesitate to ask question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an method using `split()` and arrays.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var selector="a,b,c/m,n";
var property = "width,height/font-size";

var selector_array1 = new Array();
var selector_array2 = new Array();

var property_array1;
var property_array2;

var selectors = selector.split('/');
var properties = property.split('/');
for(var i = 0; i<selectors.length; i++) {
 selectors[i] = selectors[i].split(',');
 for(var j = 0; j<selectors[i].length;j++) {
  if(i==0)
   selector_array1.push(selectors[i][j])
  else
   selector_array2.push(selectors[i][j])
 }
}
alert(selector_array1);
alert(selector_array2);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```